# Class method as decorator in python

Tags: python, class, methods, decorator, wrapper

So, im writing a library for appium tests.
I have a main class that look like this:

```
class APP():
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable1 = 1
        self.current_view = "main_screen"

    def do_operation_A(self):
        self.open_side_menu()
        do_something
        self.current_view = "side_menu"
    
    def do_operation_B(self):
        self.open_side_menu()
        do_something_else
        self.current_view = "side_menu"

    def set_landscape(self):
        self.open_settings_menu()
        configure_landscape
        self.current_view = "settings_menu"
```

The class has a lot of operations so i can do things like app.do_operation_A() or app.set_landscape() without having to first go to each menu manually (resolved inside the class)

To reduce this i want to implement a decorator to do something like this if possible:

```
class APP():
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable1 = 1
        self.current_view = "main_screen"

    #DEFINE_DECORATOR_HERE

    @side_menu
    def do_operation_A(self):
        do_something
    
    @side_menu
    def do_operation_B(self):
        do_something_else

    @settings_menu
    def set_landscape(self):
        configure_landscape
```

So i want to implement this decorators to navigate to the corresponding view and also change that variable that i use to check some things in other functions. I have seen some examples with functools.wraps but is not clear to me of how to implement the decorator inside the class to be able to modify this self variables.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a decorator means that you "wrap" your other function, i.e. you call the decorator and then call the function from inside the decorator.

E.g.:

```
import functools

def outer(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

Upon defining the function, the decorator will be called, returning the `inner` function.

Whenever you call `func`, you will in reality call `inner`, which runs it's own code, including calling the original `func` function.

So for your use case, you should be able to create decorators similar to:

```
def settings_menu(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.open_settings_menu()
        self.current_view = "settings_menu"
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner
```

Comment: Nice response! More succinct than mine. But I do think it gets a bit more clear when explicitly having `self` as first argument in the `inner` method. Then you can avoid having this `args[0]` business.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. I was just trying to make a quick example and didn't think about that.

Answer (score 1):

So a decorator is basically a function that returns another function, right?

```py
def side_menu(func):
    def wrapper():
        return func()
    
    return wrapper
```

The `wrapper`, returned by `side_menu`, will be called whenever `App().do_operationA` is called. And whenever that method is called, `self` is always the first argument. Or rather, the first argument is the instance of App, but whatever. So we could do:

```py
def side_menu(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.open_menu()
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Now, you don't want the method to present itself as `wrapper` - you like the name `do_operationA`. That's where `@functools.wraps` comes in, it makes things look and work right when decorating.

```py
def side_menu(func):
    @functools.wraps
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.open_menu()
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```